# The "-controller" option does not exist in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, model, laravel-artisan

In Laravel5 i am trying to create Model in Model folder with migration,controller and resource by using below command

```
$ php artisan make:model "Http/Model/Course" -mcr
```

Or

```
$ php artisan make:model "Http/Model/Course" -crm
```

The command works fine if i use simple command i.e.

```
$ php artisan make:model Course -mcr
```

but if i change the path of Model folder it gives error

> [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException]     The "-c"
>   option does not exist.

Kindly help me in that.

Comment: why not use `php artisan make:model ModelName -a`

Comment: Because i want to store Course model in Model folder generated in Http

Comment: So you can do this with this command `php artisan make:model "Model\MyModel" -a`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "" quotes. They are the problem.

This should work:

```
php artisan make:model Http/Model/Course -mcr
```

Also if you are not sure how a command works just add --help

```
php artisan make:model --help
```

Comment: Hi Christophvh, i tried without "" also but that is also not working. Giving the same error